# How to force Express JS to serve files from the same directory regardless of route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am writing an express app that uses a template engine called Handlebars. The html files it serves contain images that point to certain places in my root directory. This works fine for surface-level routes such as "http://localhost:5000/image" or "http://localhost:5000/login". However, when I go to a deeper route such as "http://localhost:5000/image/1", all of the images point to a nonexistent "/image" folder in my root directory. Screenshots demonstrating this here:
[image: The first image uses a surface-level route, /image]

[image: The second image uses a deeper route, /image/1]

How can I force my pages to only point to my root directory regardless of which route the user is in? I cannot simply change the src in the html files as I am using a template engine that serves the same banner image regardless of what page the user is on.

Here is my code[image]

Comment: Note: you should not post images of code, instead edit the question and embed the code there. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're approaching this from the direction.

Currently you are using relative paths in your HTML. `<img src="assets/etc…`

These are resolved by taking the base URL (usually the path to the current HTML document), removing the fragment id, query string, and everything after the last `/` and then appending the relative path.

So the resolved path will change based on the URL of the HTML document you are viewing.

---

You *could* do what you are asking for and write code so that:

```
/assets/foo
/something/assets/foo
/something-else/assets/foo
/something/something/assets/foo
```

All give you the same resource.

However:

- This would break caching of that resource
- It would be a pain to write
- You might get duplicate content penalties in search engines

So **don't do that**.

---

Instead, pick a URL for the resource and change the HTML so you are always asking for the same URL.

**Use an absolute path** which starts with a `/`.

These are resolved in a similar way to relative URLs, but instead of stripping off everything after the last `/` they strip off everything after the hostname (and optional port number).

```
<img src="/assets/etc…
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using relative paths in your template. Since you use `express.static` to serve files in the root directory, try changing the image paths to absolute paths (starting with an `/`):

```
<img src="/assets/path/to/your-image.png">
```

Comment: The example you give is how I am currently doing it. Are you saying that I have to use

<img src="http://localhost:5000/path/img.png>

instead of 

<img src="path/img.png>

If so, I can live with that. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Melissa — "The example you give is how I am currently doing it." No, it isn't. You've posted a screenshot. We can see that isn't how you are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Dedicate a separate directory for static files. Then always refer to them as an absolute path.